# How to open a cloned wiki folder?

Tags: github, libgdx

I recently cloned the libGDX wiki from https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki and I got a libgdx.wiki folder with all the content in it. My question is how do I read/open it?

Already tried using Firefox's wiki reader plug-in but it seems like that is for files and not folders.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The GitHub wiki system is implemented with Gollum, which can be run locally to parse the Markdown files in libgdx.wiki and link them up as a wiki beyond just renering the .md - check out this link for more info:

https://github.com/wicketstuff/core/wiki/Editing-Wiki-Locally